# The Performance Lab plugin creates shadow noise in photos

Tags: wordpress, image, optimization, webp

I have a problem converting **JPEG** images to **WEBP**.

So far all I've read about the **WEBP** format is that it helps with mobile optimization and generally makes the site load faster, like just converting from **JPEG** to **WEBP**, claiming that the ***quality doesn't change at all***, but it seems that it is not quite so.

I'm using Wordpress and I can't figure out if the problem is with the **Performance Lab** plugin or Wordpress itself. The biggest change is noticeable in the shadows. When the image is in the original JPEG format, there is no noise in the shadows. They render smoothly and without pixelation, but when it's in WEBP format there's noise in the shadows and I don't understand why.

Here in this screenshot, you can see what I mean:

[image]

Please tell me you see it too and I'm not crazy.

I stopped the **Performance Lab** plugin and uploaded a JPEG image and the problem went away, but I would still like the site to be well optimized and use WEBP, but I'm annoyed by this noise in the shadows.